# Is this function a solution to the ODE? My textbook insults the students that don't know....

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

It's true.

Given: $y^{(4)} + 4y^{(3)} + 3y = t$, determine if $y_1(t) = \frac{1}{3}$ and $y_2(t) = t^{ - 1}$ are solutions.

$\frac{d(y_1)}{dt} = \frac{d\left( \frac{t}{3} \right)}{dt} = \frac{1}{3}$ and the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th derivatives and all $0$. So, $0 + 4(0) + 3(1/3) = t$ so, since $1/3$ is not equal to $1$ then this is not a solution??

Checking the answer in the student solutions manual it says "Since $d/dt=1/3$, and the 2nd-4th derivatives are $0$...clearly, $y_1(t)$ is a solution." Well then.  Thanks.

Can anyone help me find the error?

Comment: One error I see is that I'm guessing you should have $y_1(t)=t/3$. I was initially confused because $1/3$ certainly isn't a solution.

Comment: With $t/3$ instead of $1/3$ it actually is pretty obvious: you have $0+0+3(t/3)=t$.

Comment: $0+0+3(t/3)=t$ which becomes $t=t$ and this means it is a solution? I thought  I was trying to make it equal $t/3$" so I thought I was going to get something like: "since $0+0+3(t/9)=t$; $1/3=1/3$ $LHS=RHS$ so its a solution"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font is tiny on my screen, but it seems that my comment above that $y_1(t)=t/3$ doesn't help because you already know that, and it must have been a typo when you wrote $1/3$. The *actual* error is this: you are taking the derivative of $y_1(t)$ when that is not indicated. The equation is
$$y^{(4)}+4y^{(3)}+3{\bf\huge y}=t$$
We have $y=t/3$, and $3(t/3)=t$. You are correct that if it were instead $y'$ then $y_1(t)$ would not be a solution.